# How to filter an array of object with dynamic array of object as input - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter an array of object (**mainArr** ) with dynamically updating object which has list of array (**arrTofilter**) which looks like bellow , I have 2 test inputs one of them is working as expected but the other one is failing.

```js
let mainArr = [{
  AREA: "INDIA",
  GROUP_DESC: "Group A",
  BUSINESS_ID: "1",
  SUB_REGION: "KARNATAKA"
}, {
  AREA: "INDIA",
  GROUP_DESC: "Group A",
  BUSINESS_ID: "2",
  SUB_REGION: "Tamilnadu"
}, {
  AREA: "INDIA",
  GROUP_DESC: "Group C",
  BUSINESS_ID: "3",
  SUB_REGION: "Kerala"
}, {
  AREA: "AFRICA",
  GROUP_DESC: "Group D",
  BUSINESS_ID: "4",
  SUB_REGION: "Nigeria"
}];

//input 1 : input array 
let arrTofilter = {
  AREA: [],
  GROUP_DESC: ['Group A', 'Group D'],
  BUSINESS_ID: ['2'],
  SUB_REGION: []
};

//so far tried code
const finalArr = mainArr.filter(({
  GROUP_DESC,
  BUSINESS_ID
}) => arrTofilter.GROUP_DESC.includes(GROUP_DESC) && arrTofilter.BUSINESS_ID.includes(BUSINESS_ID));
```

The above code works fine if the input array (arrTofilter) is like scenario 1,

in second scenario if the input array is like bellow then code fails , How can i make this work for both the inputs?

```js
//input 2 : input array 
let arrTofilter = {AREA: [], GROUP_DESC: ['Group A','Group D'], BUSINESS_ID: [], SUB_REGION: []};
```

Note:  just removing my && statement will work but my input array is huge and even the main array so I can do && for multiple inputs but again if the user sends in single input this wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check if for example `arrTofilter.GROUP_DESC` is empty or not (by checking the length of the array). If it's empty, then it should not be included as a filter. Do this for all four potential filters (AREA, GROUP_DESC, BUSINESS_ID and SUB_REGION).

```
const finalArr = mainArr.filter(({
  AREA
  GROUP_DESC,
  BUSINESS_ID,
  SUB_REGION
}) => (arrTofilter.AREA.length === 0 || arrTofilter.AREA.includes(AREA)) &&
(arrTofilter.GROUP_DESC.length === 0 || arrTofilter.GROUP_DESC.includes(GROUP_DESC)) &&
(arrTofilter.BUSINESS_ID.length === 0 || arrTofilter.BUSINESS_ID.includes(BUSINESS_ID)) &&
(arrTofilter.SUB_REGION.length === 0 || arrTofilter.SUB_REGION.includes(SUB_REGION));
```